# Unable to discover Xamarin.Forms Embedding nuget package

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am unable to discover the Xamarin.Forms Embedding nuget package.

I added a new source to my Nuget Manager: https://www.myget.org/F/xamarinforms-dev/api/v3/index.json

I also have pre-releases selected.

I have Xamarin.Forms 3.4 installed.

However, the package just doesn't show up.

The only items that show up are the following:

- Xamarin.Forms Alias
- Xamarin.FlexLayout.Engine.Yoga
- Xamarin.Forms.Design

Comment: Have you tried to do a package restore? No errors in downloading packages?

Comment: Package restore is enabled in my Tools | Options.

Comment: I think this item is no longer in Preview anymore and is now part of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when NuGet is confused which Package Source you package is in, I would suggest you change you Package Source to the desired one which can be found on the Nuget Screen.

I would suggest you check your source in the Package Source dropdown marked in the image below:

[image: Nuget Image]

Goodluck

Revert in case of queries